# Windows 10 IDA freeware 64bit cannot find main

Tags: ida

I coded a C program in vistual studio and complied in 64 bit

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!!!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And I use IDA freeware to disassembly it, I didn't see main but follow

```
public start
start proc near
jmp     start_0
start endp
```

after I clicked start_0, The following code showed

```
start_0 proc near
arg_0= qword ptr  8
mov     [rsp+arg_0], rcx
sub     rsp, 28h
call    sub_7FF691D52000
add     rsp, 28h
retn
start_0 endp
```

obviously not main too, and I also didn't find main in function table and also I found a answer in the internet

```
Windows --> Exports
```

But I only saw start function in the result

how to find main? where to find it? or do I need to set somethings?

Answer (score 0):

To find functions by name used in sources, you can load your programs symbols in IDA (pdb file).
Without symbols you can open strings view, find there `"Hello World!!!\n"` string and double-click it.
IDA View opens with the cursor on the strings address. Open XREFS window (Ctrl+X) of this string. It should contain only one entry - your `printf` function.
Double-click this entry and you will land on `printf` in your `main`.